# Использование GridView::widget

Tags: yii2, gridview

Использую представление view для разных страниц, но в одном мне необходимо, что бы показывалось в GridView::widget один столбец, а в другом нет, есть ли решение которые бы фильтровало вывод столбца во view
Например, что бы в одном варианте у меня выводился столбец с атрибутом city, а в другом нет ('attribute' => 'city')

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => false,
        'tableOptions' => [
            'class' => 'table table-bordered table table-hover'
        ],
        'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => '--'],

        'columns' => 
        [


            [
                'attribute' => 'event_data',
                'format' => ['date', 'php:d-m-Y'],

            ],

            [
            'attribute' => 'tag',
            'label' => 'Рубрика',
            'value' => function($model)
            {   

                if(isset($model->section->tag)){
                return $model->section->tag;
                }
            },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'city',
                'label' => 'Город',
                'value' => function($model)
                {      
                    return $model->cityes->name_city;  
                },
            ],

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'visible' => ($date_event == 1) ? true : false
```